# Getting POSIX PATH from finder selection

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript, automator

I am trying to build a quick action able to ls the selected folder in finder, using automator with an applescript in it. I can't make it working. It always come back to the error " Can't get the POSIX Path". Here is my code so far :

```
on run {input, parameters}
            tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to POSIX path of input
            tell application "Terminal"
                do shell script "ls " & theFiles
                activate
            end tell
            return theFiles
        end run
```

Thanks.

Comment: Somethings you have wrong with your _code_, `input` is a `list` and needs to be treated as such.  **Finder** does understand `POSIX path`, so don't use **Finder** to get a `POSIX path`, just use **AppleScript** itself. **Terminal** doesn't understand the `do shell script` _command_, use `do script` with **Terminal**. I've posted an answer that you should be able to adapt, although ask is you need help with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **Automator** *Service* I use that you can adapt to your liking:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    set theseFinderItems to {}
    repeat with aItem in input
        copy quoted form of POSIX path of aItem to end of theseFinderItems
        copy space to end of theseFinderItems
    end repeat
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "ls -aleO@ " & theseFinderItems
    end tell
end run
```

[image]

Here is a sample output in **Terminal** when selecting the **Finder** *item* and then the
 **ls -aleO@ Finder Items** *Service*, which in **macOS Mojave** and later is referred to as a *Quick Action*.

```
$ ls -aleO@ '/Volumes/RAMDisk/CAT RP6500/Service Manual - CM20160617-56278-18523.pdf' 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  - 7061976 Jun  1 21:08 /Volumes/RAMDisk/CAT RP6500/Service Manual - CM20160617-56278-18523.pdf
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS        16 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate         53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms        116 
    com.apple.quarantine         57 
$
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr6fN.png) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Yes i wasn't treating input like a list. Thank you for the help, it is working now.